# Laravel - How to assign relative path for subfolder controller?

Tags: rest, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4.0 for my web service project. I try to assign relative path to controller subfolder but still got the error message.

This is my router looks like

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'merchant'), function()
{
    Route::resource('index', 'ProductController@showIndex');
    Route::resource('product', 'CategoryController@showIndex');
    Route::resource('general', 'GeneralController@showIndex');
});
```

Current path

> /app/controllers/ProductController.php

I want to be like this one

> /app/controllers/merchant/ProductController.php

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `namespace` to achieve that.

In your controller folder make a directory called `merchant` and place your `ProductController.php` inside `Merchant` directory.

Then open your `ProductController.php` and use the following namespace on top of the file.

```
<?php namespace Merchant;

class ProductController extends /BaseController 
{
```

After that edit your route file:

```
 Route::get('index', 'Merchant\ProductController@showIndex');
```

Remove the `Route::group(array('prefix' => 'merchant'), function()`. Prefix used when you have a common url for more than one routes.

**For example:**

```
http:://laravel.com/xyz/products
http:://laravel.com/xyz/category
http:://laravel.com/xyz/posts
```

Here `xyz` is common in every URL. So, In this case, you can use group routing with prefix `xyz`

One more thing, I can see, you have used resource controller.

```
    Route::resource('index', 'ProductController@showIndex');
    Route::resource('product', 'CategoryController@showIndex');
    Route::resource('general', 'GeneralController@showIndex');
```

Do you know that By default, for resource controller, Laravel will generate 7 routes. So, You don't need to create `@showIndex` function when using resource controller.

```
Route::resource('index', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('product', 'CategoryController');
Route::resource('general', 'GeneralController');
```

More about resource controller:

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers